# PHPUnit - Stub acting like a build in type

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, stub

How do I make my stub act like an ArrayIterator, for example? I mean, I want to iterate over this stub. It's an exercise from Practical PHP Testing.

```
7.2
Write a EvenIterator which takes a FibonacciIterator an iterates only
on the even-indexed values (returning 0, 1, 3, 8, 21...).
7.3
Write tests for the EvenIterator class, stubbing out the
FibonacciIterator using an ArrayIterator in substitution, which is provided
by the Spl (otherwise it will never terminate!)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does a normal call to the FibonacciIterator look like?

Comment: It implements an iterator. You call $a = new FibonacciIterator(7). After that you may iterate over 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8. Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't the task say in fact 'use ArrayIterator as stub for FibonacciIterator'?

Comment: What sort of guide it is which teaches to write code before test?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly the task here is to test `EvenIterator` by using `ArrayIterator` as a stub for `FibonacciIterator`.
 So for example load `ArrayIterator` with array of even values, pass it to `EvenIterator` and you should get same values. Then do the same with array of odd values, and you should get empty resultset.

---

```
class EvenIteratorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

  public function testDoesNotRemoveEvens() {

    $data = array(2,4,6,8);
    $arrayIterator = new \ArrayIterator($data);
    $object = new EvenIterator($arrayIterator);

    $expected = $data;
    $actual = array();
    foreach($object as $v) {
      $actual[] = $v;
    }
    $this->assertEquals($expected,$actual);
  }

  public function testFiltersOutOdds() {

    $data = array(1,3,5,7);
    $arrayIterator = new \ArrayIterator($data);
    $object = new EvenIterator($arrayIterator);

    $actual = array();
    foreach($object as $v) {
      $actual[] = $v;
    }
    $this->assertEmpty($actual);
  }

}
```

As you can see, there's a lot of duplicated code, so some refactoring would be in place.

Comment: May you code to explain what you said? Thank you very much Mchl.

Comment: SUre. It's very simplified (and as a result a bit ugly), since I don't know details of your implementation, or which testing framework you use.

Comment: Maybe use `iterator_to_array` instead of the foreach? But +1 from me :)

Comment: foreach just seems more natural for me, but indeed _to_array would probably look better here